# Docker: "Network is unreachable" inside container

Tags: docker, networking, sshd

I want to start sshd iside Docker and perform some ssh commands in order to build image. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y which tar more util-linux-ng passwd openssh-clients openssh-server net-tools iproute; yum clean all

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

RUN /usr/sbin/sshd -D &

RUN ssh localhost echo Hello
```

And I get error here:

```
Step 13/13 : RUN ssh localhost echo Hello
 ---> Running in e40f2e1cc39e
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Network is unreachable
The command '/bin/sh -c ssh localhost echo Hello' returned a non-zero code: 255
```

And ssh 127.0.0.1 returns:

```
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

Similar behaviour with ping and wget. Container /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      0762a183aaa3
```

Any ideas whats happens here?

Answer (score 0):

Find out that dockerfile RUN command does now allow "&", so the sshd background process does not starts. I create .sh script and run /usr/sbin/sshd -D &  from it.